# bash scripting: how to change the position of artist and song name in a filename

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have the following file:

```
Song - Arist.mp3
```

i wanna know how to change it to:

```
Arist - Song.mp3
```

using bash scripting commands.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                  

trim() { echo $1; }

for i in *.mp3; do
    ARTIST=${i#*-}
    ARTISTNAME=${ARTIST%%.mp3}
    SONG=${i%-*}
    SONGTRIMMED=$(trim $SONG)
    NEW="$ARTISTNAME - $SONGTRIMMED.mp3"
    mv "$i" "$NEW"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

```
rename 's/([^-]+) - (.*).mp3/$2 - $1.mp3/' *mp3
```

rename is part of perl (gprename).